# Showing the raw json data on refreshing the page

Tags: user-interface, material-ui, server-side-rendering, conditional-rendering

I have built a mern stack gmail clone and i have deployed the project and after the deployment when i open the link and login to my application and it logged me in very well and display the data properly but when i refresh the page then the emails present on the pages shows as the raw json data and the user interface is gone

I want that the data should display normally after the refresh